# Attempting to run a jQuery.clone() within for-loop to append an element x times but getting more than desired output

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, for-loop, clonenode

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="outerContainer">
            <div class="innerContainer">
                <div class="test">test</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
 
            $(document).ready(function() {
               for(let i=1;i<5;i++) {
                $( ".test" ).clone().appendTo( ".innerContainer" );
                }
            });

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Desired output:

```
<div class="outerContainer">
     <div class="innerContainer">
       <div class="test">test</div>
       <div class="test">test</div>
       <div class="test">test</div>
       <div class="test">test</div>
       <div class="test">test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Instead I get way more elements, almost 20. I am new to jQuery and learning. I looked into jQuery.each() but it seems that method is geared toward use with arrays + objects.

Also, I am using jQuery because I need to attach eventListeners to all the cloned elements and event delegation is not possible because the elements are not within a parentContainer.

I am also currently testing to see If I can instead use a regular for-loop with cloneNode() which works to append my elements and then possibly using jQuery.each() to attach the eventListeners?

Comment: Every time your `clone()` runs again, it's happening for all of the `.test` elements that exist in that moment, which is why they're multiplying exponentially. You're cloning 1, then 2, then 4, etc.

Comment: I believe this to be correct, I also found an alternative by accident, creating the elements via javascript and executing the script as is works also.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your element which you need to cloned outside your for-loop then use `insertAfter(cloned);` to insert after  that div .

***Demo Code*** :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="innerContainer">
      <div class="test">test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var cloned = $(".test") //declare this outside
      for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        cloned.clone().insertAfter(cloned); //insert same
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because every time you are appending the `.test` inside the container it is increasing the number of elements with `.test` class. So `clone` is cloning all the elements. You can use `first` to get only the first element and then append it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    $(".test").first().clone().appendTo(".innerContainer");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outerContainer">
  <div class="innerContainer">
    <div class="test">test</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script
```